# Voting for reopen closed topics

Tags: feature-request, reopen-closed

There are several topics on Stack Overflow which are closed due for different reasons, e.g. "not constructive", etc.

I think some of them would be important for lot of people, and because they are closed, they won't be up to date after a while, because science is always changing; there are new discoveries, new improvements in every year.

I know, that closing a topic is for good reasons, but I think it would be beneficial if the Stack Overflow community should consider (for example 100 votes for reopening would reopen the topic automatically), that a closed topic is worth reopening, or not.

Comment: We already have such a feature; users can vote to reopen; 5 votes reopens a post. We have a review queue for that as well.

Comment: And keep in mind that them "being out of date" might not be a good enough reason to reopen. If you are ever wondering about the reasons behind a closure, you are free to ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed questions can be reopened by five reopen votes from 3k+ users, or one from a moderator. If you feel a question needs to be reopened, flag it for moderator attention or edit it (which automatically enters it in the Reopen Queue).

Comment: So in this case "marked as duplicate" if I send a flag, it will be reconsidered?

Comment: @inf3rno: Reconsidered yes, but duplicates are rarely reopened.